# How do I remove this shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

It gets blocked easily and I need to get this bit off so I can sort it but it’s stuck.

[image]

Comment: Chances are the ring spins off, but I'm not sure what you're hoping to accomplish. Any blockage is not part of that assembly. It's in the plumbing beyond. Do you have access from below? Have you tried a plunger or drain cleaner (to dissolve a hair clog)?

Comment: Grout is something between tile, by the way. There is none in this photo.

Comment: You don't need to open it. Get some 'sink & plughole unblocker' from any supermarket. Pour the whole bottle in, leave overnight. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Only the centre part in this picture rotates/unscrews. The outer ring looks like it will, but the lugs provide a space for water to run under the cover.

Unscrew the centre part anticlockwise with equal and opposite pressure on both the lugs at the same time. Try using both thumbs and hands first. If that fails, you need to find something which fits into the plastic and contacts the plastic lugs.

A rubber ball often works. I've even undone things like this with a small rubber dog ring/chew toy. The rubber grabs the lugs and provides good grip.

Be aware that there is always a risk of breaking it, if it is seized in place due to age/dirt/scale/etc.